# How to display string length in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and today i was trying my first example as shown below in the code section. I am using an editor called "Free Javascript Editor".
when I run the code, the browser starts and the text between the  tags is displayed but the length of the string is never shown.

am I using it wrong?? please let me know how to do it correctly

**lib**
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

**code**:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Title of the home pahe</title>

</head>

<body>

<script>

var str = new string ("MyString");
str.length;

</script>


<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't need var str = new string("xyz"). Just do var str = "xyz"

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. `string` doesn’t exist; it’s not a function, it’s not a constructor. Just use `var str = "MyString";`. I don’t even know where you have gotten the idea that you should define strings like this in JavaScript. Also, `str.length;` doesn’t do anything on its own. You need to show it _somehow_.

Comment: alert(str.length);

Comment: @Amit what if i do not want to display it in a box, i jus wannt print it on the webpage..how can i do that

Comment: use document.write

Comment: @user2121 Then you would research how to show a value on a webpage with JavaScript, obviously.

Comment: @Amit Do not use `document.write`.

Comment: @Xufox I think this is learning stuff, he can  also use document.createElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Onload event and put it inside js function.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var str = ("MyString");
            var n = str.length;
            document.getElementById("printlength").innerHTML = n;
        }
    </script>    

    <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
    <p id="printlength"></p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts are not rendered by the browser, only executed. You can, however, do something like this:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Title of the home pahe</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
  <p id="theLength"></p>

  <script>
    // No need to invoke the string constructor here.
    var str = 'MyString';
    
    // Find our placeholder element and set the textContent property.
    document.getElementById('theLength').textContent = str.length;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

It's good practice to put your script tags at the end of the `body` element - that way all of the HTML should render before the scripts are executed.

Comment: would you please tell me why did you declare <p?? what does it mean ..is it like a variable??

Comment: `<p></p>` is just an HTML paragraph element - we're just using it as a placeholder, somewhere to put our string's length. Any element could be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [document.createElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

```js
var str = "MyString";
var p = document.createElement("p");        
p.textContent = str.length;                            
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the length of your string to a variable. Then, you can show it.

```html
<span id="stringLength"></span>
<script>
  var str = "MyString";
  var length = str.length;
  document.getElementById('stringLength').textContent = 'Length: ' + length; // Show length in page
  console.log('Length: ' + length); // Show length in console
  alert('Length: ' + length); // Show length as alert
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code to this:

```
<html>    
<head>
<title>Title of the home pahe</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

var str = "MyString";
console.log(str.length);

</script>
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you must look in the developer console for the output, here is how:

- [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)
- [FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console)
- [Safari](https://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/)

Comment: i tried console.log...but id did not show any thing

Comment: @user2121 Open the console. I explained how in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

It must be String, not string. Code below works.

```
var str = new String ("MyString");
str.length;
```